# Apply span several times

Tags: android

I have the string: "0123456789".
I need to paint to specified digits from the string.
I was using SpannableStringBuilder and setting ForegroundColorSpan per digit, but it painted only first digit or range instead of selected ones.
So how can I color 0, 2 & 8 in this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
    val str = "0123456789"
        val sb = SpannableStringBuilder()

        str.forEach {
            val span = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE)
            val spannableString = SpannableString(it.toString())
            if(it == '0' || it == '2' || it == '8')
                spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            sb.append(spannableString)
        }

//        val wordtoSpan = SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers")
//
//        wordtoSpan.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        text_view.text = sb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun ini() {
        val str = "0123456789"
        val sb = SpannableStringBuilder()

        str.forEach {
            val span = ForegroundColorSpan(getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            val spannableString = SpannableString(it.toString())
            if(it == '0' || it == '2' || it == '8')
            spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_COMPOSING)
            sb.append(spannableString)
        }

        text_view.text = sb
    }
```